# DNA genetic testing from dried sweat crystals?

Tags: dna

My sons' dad died and I wanted to do any sort of genetic testing possible, as a gift to my sons.  The only item available is dried, crystallized sweat from the bridge of his Oakleys, sadly.  Would there be any significance found in such results?  And, who does this sort of testing?  Thank you.   JK

Comment: He wore these sunglasses while bicycling, intensively, 14 miles or so in one trip, mixed terrain, so I'm thinking the sweat residue may have a high concentration of his cells.